# How to simplify geometries

Tags: arcgis-desktop, geometry, editing, line

I need to reduce the number of vertex points on line segments, from:

[image: complex curve]

to:

[image]

Is there a tool for this?

Comment: If they are lines then simplify line http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Simplify_Line/007000000010000000/ or if polygons simplify polygon http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Simplify_Polygon/007000000011000000/ available with standard and advanced license. It looks like bend simplify is what you're after but be careful with your tolerances. If you want to simplify interactively there is a generalize button on the advanced edit toolbar .

Comment: http://www.bing.com/search?q=arcgis+simplify

Answer (score 2):

In QGIS you have also the Simplify geometries tool under Vector-> Geometry Tools and there are also useful plugins as PolygonSimplifier and SimpliPy.
Really useful for cleaning data vectorized from rasters and good tools for making further topology corrections faster.

Answer (score 1):

You could try the [Simplify Line](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/cartography-toolbox/simplify-line.htm) tool which:

> Simplifies lines by removing relatively extraneous vertices while
>   preserving essential shape.